# Can pull into a newly cloned repo with SSH key but not existing one on same machine

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-clone

I'm trying to do a git pull from my bitbucket repository on my remote machine via SSH

But whenever I try to pull it asks for a password but I have SSH keys setup already.

The command `$ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` works fine and returns `authenticated via ssh key.`

I can even clone to a different folder with `git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxxx/xxxx.git` and then do git pulls into that newly cloned repo successfully. It's just whenever I navigate into the original local repo and try and pull in there, it asks for a password.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . It's just whenever I navigate into the original local repo and try and pull in there, it asks for a password

When you are in the root folder of that repository, double-check its remote URL:

```
git remote -v
```

If it starts with `https://bitbucket.com/...` instead of `git@bitbucket.com:...`, that would explain the prompt for password.

If not, check also `git config -l | grep -i insteadOf`: you might have an [`url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) config rule which would change any SSH URL into an HTTPS one.